# Wildcard DNS and CNAME

Tags: domain-name-system

I have a wildcard DNS entry (A)

*.my.tld

I also have a CNAME.. that I want hit BEFORE the wildcard A entry.

something.my.tld -> something.s3.amazonaws.com

It's not imperative... but I'd like to be able to do this.
I'm using a third party for DNS as well, so I can't hack around at BIND.

Answer (score 2):

To expand upon this for the benfit of others in search for an answer on whether a DNS wildcard entry takes precedence over a "normal" subdomain entry, it looks like it varies depending on implementation:

There is a cPanel forum post if you Google "wildcard DNS precedence" which shows that a wildcard entry will take precedence, which isn't compliant to RFC 4592: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4592

Other sites suggest proper behavior for their services

I haven't tested this in practice, but my understanding is that a wildcard is supposed to match requests for non-existent names only, so in your example, the mail subdomain should be unaffected by the wildcard entry.

There's this RFC which explains it in full: rfc4592

The cPanel Technical Sales adviser may simply be incorrect, or cPanel implements wildcard DNS in a faulty manner.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind.  totally legit.

Just appears that I needed to let it propigate.

Comment: DNS does not propagate: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System#Record_caching